# "do not like" description is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, careers-germany

For the "do not like" part at the top of the profile page, the description box tells me to enter items that I *do* like. It seems the same description is used for both fields.

Comment: We'll get the correct translation put in there.

Comment: I forgot to add: I am using the German version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, we've "nicht"d that description.